# dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus.h:29:10: fatal error: 'dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h' file not found

Tags: compiling, dbus, chromeos

I am using dbus in my programme, but when i include 
`#include <dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus.h>`

I am getting error :
`dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus.h:29:10: fatal error: 'dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h' file not found`

In the folder dbus there is no `dbus-arch-deps.h` file.

I can see this file in a folder `lib64/dbus-1.0/include/dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h`

Can any one please help me to compile this?
Or any suggestion, as I am stuck badly here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
lib64/dbus-1.0/include/dbus
```

to your *cpath* variable.
like so:

```
export CPATH=/lib64/dbus-1.0/include/dbus:$CPATH
```

( this is using the absolute path, otherwise change the beginning of the path )
check it afterwards with `echo $CPATH`

then try to compile ( for example using `gcc` or `make` )